# Why isn't my form submitting?

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe checkout with a custom button and can't get it to submit my form upon returning the token successfully.

Here's my HTML:

```
<form id="payment-form" action="{% url 'shipment:confirm' %}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<button id="customButton">Join BossBox</button>

<script>
  var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'secrettestkey (I redacted this)',
    image: '/static/shipment/images/logo.png',
    email: "{{ email_address }}",
    token: function(token, args) {
        // get the form by it's ID, you would have to add the id="payment-form" to your HTML
        var $form = $("#payment-form");
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append("<input type='hidden' name='stripeToken' value='" + token + "' />");
        // and submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
  });

  document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'MyCompany',
      description: 'Monthly Membership ($29.00)',
      amount: 2900,
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

In Chrome Developers Tools this is the error that is showing up after I successfully submit my test credentials via Stripe Checkout:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: response is not defined (index):120
StripeCheckout.configure.token (index):120
onToken checkout.js:3
rpc.methods.setToken checkout.js:4
e.message checkout.js:3
(anonymous function)"
```

Comment: It looks like you have a error in your code. It looks like you forgot to assign `response` a value before calling it maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first argument you have to the token handling function is `token`. You can access the token ID in `token.id` then, not in `response.id`. You can see an example of this in the Stripe docs for a custom Checkout integration:

- https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom

(I think there's other code in the docs that use `response` as an argument, which may be where the confusion came from.)

Hope that helps,
Larry

PS I work at Stripe.